# shell script: how to correctly realize the following idea, defining variable names on the fly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Something like the following in BASH

```
iDAV=0
for line in $(cat file); do

 IFS_bk=$IFS;  IFS=' ';  arr=($line)
 if [[ ${arr[0]} == *'DAV'* ]]; then
   iDAV=$(( $iDAV+1 ))
   val$iDAV=${arr[0]}
   cal$iDAV=${arr[1]}
 fi
 IFS=$IFS_bk

done
```

when run, it complains the following

```
calc_OSZICAR: line 88: val1=12: command not found  
calc_OSZICAR: line 89: cal1=13: command not found
```

I actually expect the script to define `val1, val2, val3, ...` and `cal1, cal2,
cal3, ...` during the iteration. Anybody has any idea how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: bash v4 has associative arrays, which you might find easier to use.

Comment: Or it could have been simple arrays too, since the value of `iDAV` is always an integer...

Comment: Do you want an answer to your question, or do you want help improving your script?  The two appear to be mutually exclusive....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `declare` directive to create dynamic variables:

```
declare "val$iDAV"="${arr[0]}"
declare "cal$iDAV"="${arr[1]}"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it works. Now how to use the declared dynamic variable? I tried the following echo $val.$icnt but it would not print the value saved in val1.

Comment: you can use `echo "$val1"` OR else: `v="val$iDAV"; echo "${!v}"`

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use eval.
run this example script:

```
iDav=1
eval val$iDav=333
eval echo \$val$iDav
```